# PyQt5 иконка для приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qicon

Пытаюсь установить иконку для приложения. 
Именно, чтобы отображалась на панели задач, а не на окне приложения.

Всё ни как. Буду благодарен если поможете.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('bug.ico'))

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('bug.ico'))

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432637/setting-the-windows-taskbar-icon-in-pyqt

Comment: а для виндовс 10 есть ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

немного корявенько, и не с полной заменой иконки, но к сожалению в ваших новоязах не силён

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
# нам понадобится модуль winextras
from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QWinTaskbarButton,QWinTaskbarProgress
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))


window.show()
window.taskbar_button = QWinTaskbarButton()
# Это до кучи пример если в таскбаре надо показывать прогресс работы
#window.taskbar_progress = window.taskbar_button.progress()
#window.taskbar_progress.setRange(0, 100)
#window.taskbar_progress.setValue(50);
#window.taskbar_progress.show()
window.taskbar_button.setWindow(window.windowHandle())
window.taskbar_button.setOverlayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если компонуете в exe, то можно задать иконку `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico myapp.py`

Answer (score 3):

Когда вы запускаете приложение, Windows смотрит на исполняемый файл и пытается угадать, 
к какой `application group` оно принадлежит.

По умолчанию все скрипты Python сгруппированы в одну и ту же группу `"Python"` , поэтому будет отображаться значок Python.

Чтобы это не происходило, нам нужно предоставить Windows другой идентификатор приложения.

Код ниже делает это, вызывая `QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()`                            с пользовательским идентификатором приложения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

try:
    # Включите в блок try/except, если вы также нацелены на Mac/Linux
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin                                         #  !!!
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'                          #  !!!
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)                      #  !!!    
except ImportError:
    pass

# .. или так ..                                                                 #  !!!
#import ctypes
#myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
#ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('BLBwO.png'))

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('BLBwO.png'))
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Aleksandr вы пробовали мой вариант? не подходит ?

Comment: Nick спасибо помог!

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте расширение с .ico на .png. Первое применяйте, когда будете сворачивать в исполняемый файл .exe.