# Как сделать так, чтобы иконка приложения отображалась в таскбаре при запуске компилированного файла из .py в .exe?

Tags: python, pyqt5, компиляция, pyinstaller, icon

При компиляции через pyinstaller приложения с графическим интерфейсом на pyqt5 командой:

pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=redletter.ico --name=spaMail logic.py

Все хорошо компилируется и запускается. Но если вытащить скомпилированный экзешник, например, на рабочий стол, то при его запуске не отображаются иконки приложения в таскбаре и в верхней части открытого окна.
Уже перепробовал кучу разных способов компиляции и флагов, ничего не помогает. По-видимому, мне нужно как-то скомпилировать иконку внутрь самого экзешника, чтобы потом к ней обращаться, но как это сделать - понятия не имею... Возможно есть другие способы реализации?

Код:

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import socket
import smtplib
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QWinTaskbarButton
from gui import Ui_Form
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))

Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()  

ui = Ui_Form()              
ui.setupUi(Form)            
Form.show()                 

Form.setWindowTitle('spaMail')
Form.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))
```

*Остальной код...*

P.S. Пробовал добавить, но тоже не сработало:

```
Form.taskbar_button.setWindow(window.windowHandle())
Form.taskbar_button.setOverlayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128075/pyqt5-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1128212#1128212

Comment: @S.Nick да, я когда искал, уже натыкался на этот ответ, но, к сожалению, у меня почему-то не сработало(

Comment: попробуйте изучить статью, очень рекомендую https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/packaging-pyqt5-pyside2-applications-windows-pyinstaller/ и у вас все получится.

Comment: @S.Nick еще раз попробовал сделать как в указанной вами ссылке, но все равно ничего не изменилось. Что думаете? Если знаете, напишите пожалуйста. Просто, уже 2 вечера на это убил, никак не могу понять в чем дело...

Comment: Прочитайте статью https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/packaging-pyqt5-pyside2-applications-windows-pyinstaller/  ! Какая у вас ОС ?

Comment: @S.Nick, у меня Windows 10