# Проблема с импортом модуля "PyQt6.QtWinExtras"

Tags: python, pyqt, импорт

Для приложения решил использовать данный код, чтобы мое приложение не учитывалось в группе питона, а имела свою иконку, для решения данной проблемы воспользовался данным кодом:

```
try:
    # Включите в блок try/except, если вы также нацелены на Mac/Linux
    from PyQt6.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Но ничего не вышло, оказывается в PyQt6 нет такого модуля, получаю следующую ошибку:

```
No module named 'PyQt6.QtWinExtras'
```

Поискал ответ в гугле, ничего схожего для PyQt6 не нашел, может кто знает как решить данную проблему?

Обнаружил, что для PyQt5 есть модуль QtWinExtras, а для PyQt6 нет.

Пост откуда читал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128075/pyqt5-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/1128212#1128212).

---

Нашел еще решение альтернативное [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105).
Но при запуске из Pycharm, иконка отображается, но после pyinstaller, после процесса сборки exe формата, и при запуске этого исполняемого файла иконка теряется.

Comment: @S.Nick привет, можете подсказать, почему в PyQt6 нет этого модуля?

Comment: DaymaNkinG, я PyQt6 еще не осваивал. Попробуйте почитать https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/extras-changes-qt6.html